# Interpretation of main effects in mixed regression with covariate

Tags: mixed-model, predictor

I am trying to analyse the effects of 3 different psychological interventions on my outcome (imagery vividness) on 3 timepoints in a linear mixed regression model in SPSS. I also want to add a covariate (therapist).

I added the covariate into the model (therapist, therapist by dummy condition, therapist by time, therapist by time by condition, all using separate dummies of course). The interactions of therapist by time are significant when using likelihood testing. 
The interaction effect of the treatments by time are not significant.

So, I want to investigate whether there are main effects of time or treatment. I am unsure how to do this, given the significant interaction of therapist by time (hence, I think I cannot use likelihood testing where I would compare the model with time effects to the one without as it is also a term in the covariate interaction). 
Moreover, how do I properly interpret the results?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CV.

When there is an interaction, the overall main effects can't be evaluated. That's pretty much what an interaction means. That is, the effect of one variable on the dependent variable is different at different levels of the other independent variable.

In your case, the effect of time can only be evaluated at each level of therapist and the effect of therapist can only be evaluated at each level of time.